# RegEx omit optional prefix in UPN or displayName

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to get only the "nonpersonalizedusername" including its number or the surname.
To add more detail, I'd like to accomplish something like:
If there's an @-Symbol, get me everything that is in front of that @-Symbol, otherwise get me the whole string.
Plus, if then there's a dot "." in it, get me everything after that dot.

Let's assume I have the following stringsof userPrincipalNames and/or displayNames:

```
nonpersonalizedusername004
nonpersonalizedusername019@domaina.local
prefixc.nonpersonalizedusername044@domaina.local
nonpersonalizedusername038@domainb.local
prefixa.nonpersonalizedusername002@domaina.local
prefixb.nonpersonalizedusername038@domainb.local
givenname.surname
givenname.surname@domaina.local
```

What I got so far is this expression:

```
^(?:.*?\.)?(.+?)(?:@.*)?$
```

but this only works, if there's an @-Symbol AND that "prefixing"-Dot in the string OR neither Dot nor @-Symbol.
If there's an @-Symbol, but no prefixing-dot, I'm getting only that "local"-part from the end.

https://regex101.com/r/1aflGH/1

Comment: So, `^(?:[^.@]*\.)?([^@]+?)(?:@.*)?$`? https://regex101.com/r/lZkFv6/2

Comment: Without the lazy quantifier: `^(?:[^@.]*\.)?([^@]+)(?:@.*)?$`

Comment: Right, it just remained from OP's variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:[^@.]*\.)?([^@]+)(?:@.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZkFv6/3). The `\n` is added to the negated character classes at regex101 as the test is run against a single multiline string.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^@.]*\.)?` - an optional sequence of any zero or more chars other than `@` and `.` and then a `.`
- `([^@]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `@` char
- `(?:@.*)?` - an optional sequence of `@` and then the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Works as expected. Many thanks! Indeed I thought, I could built an Expression with an optional non-Capturegroup+Capture+non-Capture in the way I provided in my initial Question.

Answer (score 0):

You might optionally repeat matches until the last dot before the @, and then capture the rest after that do till the @ in group 1.

```
^(?:[^@.]*\.)*([^@.]+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^@.]*\.` Optionally repeat matching any char except `@` or `.`, then match `.`
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^@.]+`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g0kd0s/1)

Powershell example

```
$s = @"
nonpersonalizedusername004
nonpersonalizedusername019@domaina.local
prefixc.nonpersonalizedusername044@domaina.local
nonpersonalizedusername038@domainb.local
prefixa.nonpersonalizedusername002@domaina.local
prefixb.nonpersonalizedusername038@domainb.local
givenname.surname
givenname.surname@domaina.local
"@

Select-String '(?m)^(?:[^@.\n]*\.)*([^@.\n]+)'  -input $s -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Output

```
nonpersonalizedusername004
nonpersonalizedusername019
nonpersonalizedusername044
nonpersonalizedusername038
nonpersonalizedusername002
nonpersonalizedusername038
surname
surname
```

Comment: does work well at regex101.com, but i can't get it to work in Powershell :/

Comment: @BaBa I think it will work in Powershell, see [this example](https://tio.run/##Hcu7CsIwFIDh2TxFCA5JpUGhk0v7Bo4OtYVDekoDuZELiuKzR@n2w8cf/BNj2tCYWvXKWYi46peSzrvwB@/A6DcuJWF0YPHcdcPiLWgH0ngFhtHWQlYb5Wzm/XWcBzk1DykavudJMCHIhxzuUWdsbyWHkulxXzCNl4l8a/0B) If you have multiple strings, you might also add using the multiline modifier `(?m)^(?:[^@.]*\.)*([^@.]+)`